# The provider attribute in peristence.xml file of JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm just new to using JPA, so sorry if this a stupid question. Just a little confused.

The provider attribute in persistence.xml - should this always be an ORM framework? (e.g. hibernate , eclipse link/toplink ). So in essence, JPA is just like an abstract for an ORM framework implementation in your database? am i correct?

what if there was no provider attribute set in persistence.xml? what would be its default?

Comment: Are you really waiting for help, even if you have had questions with answers and without upvoting a single one? Please take a look at the [tour of this site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I have no provider specified (though Hibernate is ultimately my provider) and log4j gives me the warning "HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead." So I'm guessing it defaults to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider